# What does request.getParameter return?

Tags: java, jsp

// index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="backend.jsp">
<input type="text" name="one" />
<input type="submit value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In backend.jsp what does request.getParameter("one"); return?

`request.getParameter("one").getClass().getName();`

returns java.lang.String, so it must be a String right?

However I cannot do

```
String one = request.getParameter("one");
if (!"".equals(one)) {}
```

or

```
if (one != null) {}
```

This is obvious, because variable one does not return null. Is

```
if (one.length() > 0) {}
```

only way to go, or are there better solutions or a better approach? I am considering both solutions to be on jsp. Using a servlet (although jsp is a servlet) is a different use case in this scenario.

Comment: I advise you to read the javadocs before asking questions like this.  It saves everyone's time.  In this particular case you seem to have made assumptions that are incorrect, and that reading the javadoc would have corrected.

Comment: Thank you for reinforcing my intent. Except my last paragraph I am essentially saying same thing i.e read javadoc before commenting, so that people would not comment hastily or outside problem scope. I wanted to direct people to third paragraph after knowing these basics. I did not do it directly, sorry for that. Cheers!!

Comment: why are you saying we cannot do the other two cases?

Answer (score 41):

Per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist.

Do note that it is possible to submit an empty parameter - such that the parameter exists, but has no value.  For example, I could include `&log=&somethingElse` into the URL to enable logging, without needing to specify `&log=true`.  In this case, the value will be an empty String (`""`).

Answer (score 4):

```
String onevalue;   
if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("one")!=false) 
{
onevalue=request.getParameter("one").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `if (one.length() > 0) {}` and `if (!"".equals(one)) {}` will check against an empty foo parameter, and an empty parameter is what you'd get if the the form is submitted with no value in the `foo` text field.

If there's any chance you can use the Expression Language to handle the parameter, you could
access it with `empty param.foo` in an expression.

```
<c:if test='${not empty param.foo}'>
    This page code gets rendered.
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of this. This is indeed a nice solution (I will use it, if I don't get around this problem my way), but I was more eager to know how did people get around this problem in the traditional sense. E.g If there are some cases where you could compromise or break the code (say NullPointerException), only when checking length. It returns String, but did I miss something?

Comment: You could get a NullPointerException if the <input> is missing from your form because then the parameter would be null.