# Pass Two different values on a form to a servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Given the following HTML:

```html
<form action="" name="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" method="post">
    <select name="opcao">
        <option value="Did not like">Did not like</option>
        <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
        <option value="Liked" selected="selected">Liked</option>
        <option value="Loved!">Loved!</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is it possible to get the name of the form and from the select tag to the same servlet as different parameters?

Comment: Why don't you try to pass them as session variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML form name is NOT submitted as part of the request. Although if you want, you can pass as form hidden field as below:

```
 <form name="myForm" action="/my_servlet">
   <input type="hidden" name="htmlFormName" value="myForm"/>
    ....
```

However if you have two form fields, then they are passed to servlet and can be accessed using `request.getParameter("fieldName")` method inside the servlet..

Comment: ok so i can use: `request.getParameter("fieldName")` for the form and `request.getParametervalues("opcao")` for the combobox (select) correct?

Comment: Please see....http://support.dataweb.com/Help/default.view?Topic=Request.getParameterValues()          &          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425305/what-does-request-getparameter-return