# Unable to identify where request.getParameter parameter value comes from there isn't q declaration

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am trying to complete a tutorial about autocomplete functionality but could understand a crucial point. There is "q" in the getparameter which isn't defined any part of the code. I didn't understand why it is "q" but when I changed it to "a"

```
<%-- 
    Document   : getdata
    Created on : Nov 11, 2015, 8:37:33 AM
    Author     : .........
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="net.viralpatel.autocomplete.DummyDB"%>
<%
    DummyDB db = new DummyDB();

    String query = request.getParameter("q");

    List<String> countries = db.getData(query);

    Iterator<String> iterator = countries.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String country = (String)iterator.next();
        out.println(country);
    }
%>
```

----- index.jsp ----

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Nov 11, 2015, 8:28:14 AM
    Author     : .....
--%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>  
    <style>
        input {
            font-size: 120%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Country</h3>
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country"/>

    <script>
        $("#country").autocomplete("getdata.jsp");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a newbie and couldn't get where "q" stands for. It should be declared somewhere but I couldn't find. Following is the tutorial link.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/

Comment: q is a GET request parameter

Comment: It is a parameter sent from the autocomplete and contains the letters entered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does request.getParameter return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425305/what-does-request-getparameter-return)

Comment: thanks madalin but in that example you refer there is a text variable named "one" and they are calling the "one" in the other jsp. I didn't understand where "q" comes from  because it is no where. type="text" name="one". I am asking why it is "q"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` is the parameter sent by autocomplete plugin to the server. From the source code of [jquery.autoComplete.js](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/lib/jquery.autocomplete.js):

```
function makeUrl(q) {
    var url = options.url + "?q=" + encodeURI(q);
    for (var i in options.extraParams) {
        url += "&" + i + "=" + encodeURI(options.extraParams[i]);
    }
    return url;
};
```

Observe the parameter `q` being added to the URL. This function `makeUrl` is invoked while making ajax request to the server.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for reviewing and answering my question

Comment: This is btw not the jquery UI autocomplete which uses `terms`

Comment: Dear mplungjan. I am not the expert of the issue and couldn't understand from your short responses what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: there is a jQuery UI version of autocomplete. This is not it.